# Why can I put a struct into an array on a playground but not in a view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Why does this work fine on a playground but when I put it into a viewController it returns a "viewController.type does not have a member named extent"

It's driving me mad so I'd really appreciate any help!!!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct TopicBook {

        var name: String
        var species: [String]
        var subject: String
        var rotation: [String]
        var unit: String
        var extra: String
        var content: String
        var level: [(Int,Int)]

        init(name: String, species: [String], subject: String, rotation: [String], unit: String, extra: String, content: String, level: [(Int,Int)]) {

            self.name = name
            self.species = species
            self.subject = subject
            self.rotation = rotation
            self.unit = unit
            self.extra = extra
            self.content = content
            self.level = level
        }
    }

    var extext = TopicBook (name: "Name" , species: ["species","species"], subject: "subject", rotation: ["rotation"], unit: "unit", extra: "extra", content: "content", level: [(1,1)])

    let sete = [extent]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
struct TopicBook {

    var name: String
    var species: [String]
    var subject: String
    var rotation: [String]
    var unit: String
    var extra: String
    var content: String
    var level: [(Int,Int)]

    init(name: String, species: [String], subject: String, rotation: [String], unit: String, extra: String, content: String, level: [(Int,Int)]) {

        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.subject = subject
        self.rotation = rotation
        self.unit = unit
        self.extra = extra
        self.content = content
        self.level = level
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var extent:TopicBook?
   var extent2:TopicBook?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        extent = TopicBook (name: "Name" , species: ["species","species"], subject: "subject", rotation: ["rotation"], unit: "unit", extra: "extra", content: "content", level: [(1,1)])

        extent2 = TopicBook (name: "JustToShow" , species: ["JustToShow","JustToShow"], subject: "JustToShow", rotation: ["JustToShow"], unit: "JustToShow", extra: "JustToShow", content: "JustToShow", level: [(2,2)])


    }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool){
  super.viewDidAppear(true)

    //If you want it to have multiple TopicBooks inside, do this
//var seteMutable:[TopicBook] = [ ]
//seteMutable =[extent!]
//seteMutable.append(extent2!)
//let seteTrial = seteMutable

//println(seteTrial[0].name)
//println(seteTrial[1].name)

//else if you want it to have just one TopicBook inside, do this
    let sete = [extent!]
    // sete is a TopicBook array now
    //you can use sete[0]
    //Placing it inside viewDidAppear is an example, you can define "sete" in anywhere you will use it. 
    //viewDidAppear gets called after viewDidLoad, this is why i put it here
    }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, firstly I missed of the square brackets in the last line which are quite crucial! Secondly, I don't think that helped, the error message went away, but I cant use the sete in anything just comes up with 'unresolved identifier'?

Comment: You said "this works fine on a playground and gives this error". So I gave you the code that got rid of the error without changing any part of your code. Your "working on playground" version didn't include square brackets. So it is not in this question's scope whether you can able to use it anywhere or not. @AlexMcGhee

Comment: Yep, that was entirely my fault, I just missed off the square brackets when writing it on here. The code including the square brackets worked on playground but didn't work in the view controller. Do you know how I could make the code work, including the square brackets please?

Comment: Or should I ask a new question? I'm new to the forum and don't know how it works :/

Comment: "unresolved identifier" error means "sete" is defined as local and you try to use it from outside of its scope. @AlexMcGhee